# Sharing Flash Pro/Builder projects between OSX and Windows

Tags: flash, cross-platform, flash-builder, flash-cs5

My buddy and I are gearing up for a game jam and we're hoping to use Flash to build our project. One possible problem is that he's got a PC laptop, and I've got a MacBook.

What's the status of cross-platform development in Flash? I'd love to be able to drop something into an SVN repo and pull everything down without regard to the OS, but I'm not convinced that will be very smooth. It seems like I can move around ActionScript source and .fla files without too much issue, but Flash Builder projects seem pretty gnarly, e.g. they appear to have references to them outside of the project folder.

Is there an easy way to migrate project data in such a away that we can develop *and* debug regardless of OS? Maybe version-controlling all the portable content (.as, .fla, raw assets) and the importing into our respective project environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in this topic: it turns out Flash Builder projects work just fine in cross-platform situations. We used Subclipse (the Eclipse IDE's SVN plug-in) and imported the project folder into our respective environments, and everything went without a hitch.